# C# Update Database using gridview

Tags: ms-access

i like to know how i can update edited column or row in datagridview?

this is my code it's display my datagridview but when i edit it and reload the view button
it doesn't update.

thanks for help in advance

public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //View
        {

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();



        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Employees", con);

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        da.Fill(dt);


        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;





        con.Close();



    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();



    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(CMD);

    da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Employees", con);

    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    da.Fill(dt,"EmployeeName");


    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    dataGridView1.DataMember = "EmployeeName";





    con.Close();
```

Comment: Hope This changes Helps you

Comment: Maraming Samalat / Thank You Very Much! =)